# Переменные в массиве

Tags: javascript

Дали задание найти общие символы двух строк. Смог бы решить если бы мне самому нужно было вводить значения в массив. Однако вводить должен сам пользователь. И я вот не понимаю как это сделать.  Когда проверяю символ под индексом 1, 2, 3 и.т.д. - выводит undefined. Помогите пожалуйста с решением! Привел простой пример ниже.

```
var b = 1352254; 
var c = 1032; 
var a = [b]; 
var v = [c];
alert(a[3]);
```

Comment: массив вам не нужен.toString(), length и charAt(n)

Comment: Надо использовать split() для деления строки по буквам, далее крестьянским способом: Берешь двойной цикл в первом пробегаешь весь первый массив, во втором цикле сверяешь его со всеми элементами второго массива.

Comment: @nick_n_a большое спасибо!

Comment: @Oma хорошо, попробую)

Comment: в ответ не могу вставить, капча не грузится. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slippyk/xm4b6ve0/) здесь код

Comment: @slippyk спасибо, главное только разобраться в коде

Comment: @Mark_8 алгоритм взят [отсюда](http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=javascript-obyedineniye-peresecheniye-raznost-massivov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function IntersecArrays(A, B)
{
    var m = A.length, n = B.length, c = 0, C = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++)
     { var j = 0, k = 0;
       while (B[j] !== A[ i ] && j < n) j++;
       while (C[k] !== A[ i ] && k < c) k++;
       if (j != n && k == c) C[c++] = A[ i ];
     }
   return C;
}

function GetArrays()
{
  var arr1 = (document.getElementById("str1").value).split('');
    var arr2 = (document.getElementById("str2").value).split('');
    document.getElementById("common").innerText = IntersecArrays(arr1, arr2);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="str1">
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" value="" id="str2">
<br />
<br />
<button onclick="GetArrays()">Общее</button><label id="common"></label>
```

Answer (score -1):

вот пример программы такой, но оно выводит индекс.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4],
    b = [6,7,6,4];
    for(var i = 0;i < a.length;i++){
      if(a[i] == b[i]){
          console.log(i);
    }
}
```